# Regular Expression for a different mechanism of substring

Tags: java, regex

I was doing a project where in, I am getting source code in form of a string.

There is a method lets say `a1.check(a2);`

Now I am looping through the string to try and determine how check variables are used, i.e when I get the index of `.check(`, i want to extract `a1` and `a2`. Trick is `a1` can go to any variable i.e `a100` or `a1000` and same case with `a2`.

Is it possible to write a regular expression for this? If yes could you help me with it? I am clueless about regex and I have written using simple indexes and substrings.

Comment: I really have no idea what you're trying to do. Please clarify or give clear examples or something.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that both `a1` and `a2` stand for alphanumeric strings (i.e. ASCII letters/numbers, plus underscore), you could use

```
(\w+)\.check\((\w+)\)
```

In Java:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(\\w+)\\.check\\((\\w+)\\)");
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
while (regexMatcher.find()) {
    a1 = regexMatcher.group(1)
    a2 = regexMatcher.group(2)
    // Do something with a1 and a2
}
```